# extjs keymap on Ext.form.field.Text

Tags: javascript, extjs

I'm trying to capture when the user presses the enter key in the textfield. I've tried using the listeners config parameter, and I've tried the KeyMap class. I can't get either to work. Here's my code for the keymap:

```
var bcTextField = Ext.create('Ext.form.Text', {
    xtype: 'textfield',
    emptyText: 'Enter Barcode/Accession Number',
    width: 200,
    margin: '0'
});
var map = new Ext.util.KeyMap({
    target: bcTextField,
    binding: [{
        key: 13,
        fn: function() {
            console.log(arguments);
        }
    }]
});
```

Does anyone have any idea what I could be doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually `KeyMap` binds to the HTML element not the ExtJs object. So I would recommend first replace `target: bcTextField` with `target: bcTextField.getEl()`

Comment: that was most likely the problem. I got it to work, however, with bcTextField.on('specialkey'). Thanks!